# Discord.py bot send update when a game is free on the epic store

Tags: python, discord.py

I would like my discord bot to send a text message whenever a game is listed as a free game on the epic store. I use the following code to get the name of the game, how do I get this to run whenever the value is updated?

Edit: I found the URLs from [here](https://github.com/Axyss/AutomatiK/blob/master/AutomatiK%20files/modules/epic.py).

```
import requests
import json

@bot.command(name='free', pass_context=True, aliases=['fr'])
async def free(ctx, message):
 
    try:
        ENDPOINT = "https://store-site-backend-static.ak.epicgames.com/freeGamesPromotions?locale=es-ES&country=ES&allowCountries=ES"
        URL = "https://www.epicgames.com/store/us-US/product/"
        raw_data = requests.get(ENDPOINT)
        raw_data = json.loads(raw_data.content) 
        raw_data = raw_data["data"]["Catalog"]["searchStore"]["elements"]  # Cleans the data
        processed_data = []
        for i in raw_data:
                        try:
                            if i["promotions"]["promotionalOffers"]:
                                game = i["title"] 
                                processed_data.append(game)
                        except TypeError:
                            pass
        await ctx.message.channel.send("**{}** is now free on the Epic store!".format(processed_data[0]))

    except Exception:
        
        pass
```

Comment: *I was wondering if this is possible?* - https://freestuffbot.xyz/ exists, so yes, it's possible.

Comment: Good to know! Any idea where to help find out how to do this? I want to improve with this type of coding so I would like to code it myself

Comment: Please [edit] your post to narrow it down to a *specific programming question*. If it helps, break the problem into parts and pick the one you're having trouble with. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Ok I edited it please let me know if this is better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this has been done before many times, and only requires **1.** checking the data you want by scraping in a loop, and **2.** posting your update to Discord.

To learn how to scrape Epic games for the data you want, you will need to know the main libraries **bs4** (Beautiful Soup 4 for parsing HTML) and **requests** (high level HTTP networking) -- so here's some very basic resources:

- https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/
- https://realpython.com/python-requests/

For your Discord posting implementation, there's no need to crack a nut with a sledgehammer, check out this much simpler implementation for Discord webhooks [here](https://birdie0.github.io/discord-webhooks-guide/discord_webhook.html) & [here](https://gist.github.com/Bilka2/5dd2ca2b6e9f3573e0c2defe5d3031b2) that require basically one api call.

On a side note, always review the websites ToS before, so you can check what data can be scraped and how you can use the data you scrape.

Comment: I would only add that `discord.py` has [task()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html) to run function periodically - so it can be used in **1.** instead of `loop`